# Gdiplus::Image from byte array

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

I'm executing dcraw and using an anonymous pipe to pipe it to a char array.

My question is how can I create a `Gdiplus::Image` object from a char array containing the jpeg image? Without writing and reading it from the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Gdiplus::Bitmap` from an `IStream` source. There are built-in Windows APIs  that can do this for you - see [CreateStreamOnHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Another way is to write your own class that implements `IStream`.

[Here is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI) using `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` to load PNG resources from memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CByteArray byteArr;

    //fullfill byteArr
    COleStreamFile stream;
    if(!stream.CreateMemoryStream(NULL))
    {
        return;
    }
    stream.Write(byteArr.GetData(), byteArr.GetSize());
    stream.SeekToBegin();
    m_pSnapShot.reset(::new Gdiplus::Image(stream.GetStream( )));
```